# Elisp: Save HTML file and view it in one stroke

Tags: firefox, emacs, elisp

This sort of works, only you must already have that page open. Optimally, it would go to the correct tab or, if not available, open a new tab. To do this, I must somehow get the state of the browser (Iceweasel in my case). (I should check if there is a browser at all, I now realize. But that is easier, I can do that with ps.)

```
(defun save-source-update-browser ()
  "Save file, go to Iceweasel, hit F5."
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (shell-command "wmctrl -a iceweasel")
  (shell-command
    (concat "echo -e 'KeyStrPress F5\nKeyStrRelease F5' | xmacroplay "
            (getenv "DISPLAY")
            " 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null" )))
```

How do I get the state of the browser so I can make it work for real? Now it updates the current page. What if that page is not the page being edited? Then it doesn't make sense to view it and update it.

Comment: It says "To do this, I must somehow get the state of the browser".

Answer (score 0):

Swank-js can do some automatic refreshing for you.  It might be a little too beefy for what you're after; However it does provide some extra functionality that you might find useful.

What you would want to do is set up a sticky remote, and then you can issue the command  `M-x slime-js-reload`.  You could even bind it to F5 if you like.

https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js

**Disclosure:** I am one of the maintainers of the Swank.js project.

Comment: Actually I really want the state of the browser. That would be useful not only now but in other cases as well. I've never heard of Swank, what is it?

Comment: Oh?  Then you probably want to have a look at swank-js then.  Swank is the backend to "Slime" which is the Superior Lisp Interaction Mode for Emacs.  It doesn't just have to be about lisp however, there is a clojure backend, scheme backends, and others.  Swank-js will give you the ability to use slime with node.js and your browser (through socket.io).  Al alternate is to sue mozrepl (assuming that iceweasel can install firefox extensions).  swank-js is cross platform, but ultimately only gives you control over the window object.  Mozrepl is Firefox only, but full browser control.